# R lists of characters to one data.frame

Tags: r

I've been looking around for quite a while now, but can't seem to solve this problem, although I feel like it should be an easy one.

I have 54 factors containing differing amounts of strings, names of pathways to be exact. For example, here are two factors with the elements they contain:

```
> PWe1
 [1] Gene_Expression                                        
 [2] miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase            
 [3] Generic_Transcription_Pathway

> PWe2
  [1] miR-targeted_genes_in_epithelium_-_TarBase                           
  [2] miR-targeted_genes_in_leukocytes_-_TarBase                           
  [3] miR-targeted_genes_in_lymphocytes_-_TarBase                          
  [4] miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase
```

What I would like to do is take these, and combine them into one big data frame with 54 columns, where each column has the names of one corresponding factor. I've tried cbind, cbind.data.frame and a couple of other options but those return numeric values instead of strings.

---

Expected output:

```
PWe1 PWe2
Gene_Expression miR-targeted_genes_in_epithelium_-_TarBase
miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase miR-targeted_genes_in_leukocytes_-_TarBase
Generic_Transcription_Pathway miR-targeted_genes_in_lymphocytes_-_TarBase
NA miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase
```

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to R, could anyone nudge me towards a possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does each factor have the same number of strings? Please add at least one more factor and show the output that should result.

Comment: So in your example you show 3 factors? What is PWe1?

Comment: Sotos I think `PWe1` is the factor with 3 strings associated with it.

Comment: Uhh..ok...so factor 2 would be PWe2 for example? In that case you basically need to combine uneven columns?

Comment: Hi! I calrified the question, sorry for not being clear. Pwe1, PWe3, PWe ... are the factors, that contain differing amounts of strings

Comment: Yes, exactly! I need to combine uneven columns of characters

Comment: So you basically need to set your 54 vectors(?) to be the same length and then bind them

Comment: Yes! And sorry, they are vectors indeed

Comment: You have one object for each vector? Are they named `PWe1` to `PWe54`? If so, maybe you can try: `l<-mget(paste0("PWe",1:54))` followed by `do.call(cbind,lapply(l,function(x) {length(x)<-max(lengths(l));x}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 <- max(length(v1), length(v2))
length(v1) <- l1
length(v2) <- l1
cbind(as.character(v1), as.character(v2))
#     [,1]                                          [,2]                                         
#[1,] "Gene_Expression"                             "miR-#targeted_genes_in_epithelium_-_TarBase" 
#[2,] "miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase" "miR-#targeted_genes_in_leukocytes_-_TarBase" 
#[3,] "Generic_Transcription_Pathway"               "miR-#targeted_genes_in_lymphocytes_-_TarBase"
#[4,] NA                                            "miR-#targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern="PW"))            #<--- Create list with all necessary vectors.
ind <- lengths(lst)                      #<--- find maximum length
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, 
  lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(ind))))    #<--- Convert to data.frmae
#                                          PWe1                                        PWe2
# 1                             Gene_Expression  miR-targeted_genes_in_epithelium_-_TarBase
# 2 miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase  miR-targeted_genes_in_leukocytes_-_TarBase
# 3               Generic_Transcription_Pathway miR-targeted_genes_in_lymphocytes_-_TarBase
# 4                                        <NA> miR-targeted_genes_in_muscle_cell_-_TarBase
```

Comment: Made a comment at the same time with the same idea. +1

Comment: I like this better :)

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your factors to characters before you use cbind, you don't get numeric values:

```
    testFrame <- data.frame(cbind(as.character(PWe1), as.character(PWe3))
```

If the length of both vectors differs, cbind throws a warning and elements of the shorter vectors will be replicated. If that is unsatisfying in your case, maybe a data.frame object might not be the right choice?

Comment: OP is not referring to factors in the R sense. And the strings are uneven lengths, cbind will recycle.